# Background image in fancybox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

How can I use an background image in a fancybox window?
Is this possible? If so how can this be done?

http://fancybox.net

Answer (score 0):

Your target content, an `inline` content for instance, should have the background image like :

html

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="inline"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#inline {
    background: url("http://thumbnails.illustrationsource.com/huge.103.519781.JPG") top left no-repeat;
    width: 344px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoScale : false // use fitToView for v2.x
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PbvUj/)</kbd>